# Is it possible to include format of a thymeleaf fragment

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm looking for a way to include the structure of a thymeleaf fragment into a page.
What i mean by that is as follows:

The fragmend defined as follows:

```
<div class="container" th:fragment="container">
    <div class="row">
        {the content of the page continues here}
    </div>
</div>
```

The page template:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/main:: container">
    {I can continue here for eq, <div class="col-md-5"></div>}
</div>
```

I dont't know if this is possible but i'm looking for a way to do this.

Comment: Look up thymeleaf layout dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [layout dialect of Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html), this can be done by adding
`<th:block layout:fragment="content"/>` to desired layout and using this as parent element in your view.